# objective c - How to tell if an NSURL is formatted as a phone number

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, nsurl, phone-number

I have an iOS app with a UITextView that auto detects links and phone numbers. What I want to do is intercept when a link is clicked using this:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
```

and then I need to check whether the URL is a web link or a phone number.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? The only way I can think of is to convert it to a string and check if it starts with @"tel" but there has to be a better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There IS a better way.

An NSURL object has an attribute of scheme, which will identify what type of URL it is.

```
if ([URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"tel"]) {
     // handle telephone case here
} else {
    // handle http or other case here
}
```

The documentation says the scheme could be considered the protocol in most cases:

> NOTE
>
> The term “protocol” is also sometimes used when talking about network-based URL schemes. However, not all URL schemes are networking protocols—data:// URLs, for example.

Check this section of the NSURL docs for more information about how to split apart the URL to use the parts you need:
[Accessing the Parts of the URL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW21) (valid link as of 5/21/15)

Comment: I added some additional information and link to the documentation, for reference. Let me know if you need any more help, or if this answer isn't what you're looking for.